# Saving a value between successive macro calls

Tags: math-mode, macros, expl3

I want to save a variable value between calls of a macro, the intention being not to have to repeat a whole lot of parameters in successive calls. It all works as intended if in textmode. If I invoke mathmode individually for each call, i.e. `$\myMacro$`, which is what I want to do, the variable is reset for each call. Is there a workaround?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%   VARIABLE DECLARATIONS:
\tl_new:N \savevar_rn_tl
\tl_set:Nn \savevar_rn_tl {INIT}
\NewDocumentCommand\myMacro{O{1}O{Z}}   
{
    !*\tl_use:N \savevar_rn_tl*!        \\
    \str_case:nn {#1} 
        {
            {1}
            {
                #2\\        
                \tl_set:Nn \savevar_rn_tl {#2@#2}
            }
            {2}
            {
                \tl_use:N \savevar_rn_tl \\
                \tl_set:Nn \savevar_rn_tl {RESET}
            }
        }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{The way I want to use it, but savevar is not preserved between calls:}
$\myMacro$\\
$\myMacro[2]$\\
$\myMacro[1][\alpha]$\\
$\myMacro[2]$\\
\section{savevar is preserved between calls, but only if calls are made in textmode:}
\myMacro\\
\myMacro[2]\\
\myMacro[1][W]\\
\myMacro[2]\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think, this is an grouping issue. Use `\tl_gset:Nn`

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of saving the value Z as Z@Z.

Comment: @egreg Just for the purpose of the MWE - an easily recognisable value to see if it is preserved correctly.

Comment: Instead of two optional arguments, you could use `\myMacro` where you now use `\myMacro[1]` and `\myMacro*` for the “use and reset case”. This way you don't have to use `[1]` when you need the optional argument. So the calls would be `$\myMacro$ $\myMacro*$ $\myMacro[\alpha]$` `$\myMacro*$`.

Answer (score 4):

Switching to math mode enters a group, so `\tl_set:Nn` sets the value only within the group, but not outside. If the value should be preserved, `\tl_gset:Nn` (global set) has to be used.

The apparent 'reset' is just due to the fact that `\savevar_rn_tl` outside still has the value of the initial setting and the filling with `#2@#2` is only locally, within the group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%   VARIABLE DECLARATIONS:
\tl_new:N \g_savevar_rn_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_savevar_rn_tl {INIT}
\NewDocumentCommand\myMacro{O{1}O{Z}}   
{
    !*\tl_use:N \g_savevar_rn_tl*!        \\
    \str_case:nn {#1} 
        {
            {1}
            {
                #2\\ 
                Value\space before:\tl_use:N \g_savevar_rn_tl \\
                \tl_gset:Nn \g_savevar_rn_tl {#2@#2}
                Value\space after:\tl_use:N \g_savevar_rn_tl \\
              }
            {2}
            {
              Before: \tl_use:N \g_savevar_rn_tl \\
              \tl_gset:Nn \g_savevar_rn_tl {RESET}
              Value: \tl_use:N \g_savevar_rn_tl \\
            }
        }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{The way I want to use it, but savevar is not preserved between calls:}
$\myMacro$\\
$\myMacro[2]$\\
$\myMacro[1][\alpha]$\\
$\myMacro[1][\beta]$
\section{savevar is preserved between calls, but only if calls are made in textmode:}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_clear:N \g_savevar_rn_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
\myMacro[1][A]\\
\myMacro[2]\\
\myMacro[1][W]\\
\myMacro[2]\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The name of the variable should be `\g_savevar_rn_tl` (every variable should have either the `g` or the `l` prefix).

Comment: @egreg: Yes, agreed, but `\tl_gset:Nn` is needed anyway, I suppose? The `\g_` is only a name convention

Comment: Yes, of course, but the `g_` prefix will also help in remembering what function to use.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, that's true. I changed it -- please bear me, I am still new in `expl3` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, it is another step forward.

Comment: @egreg As an aside: I only ever approach the `StackExchange` if I have a hundred plus lines of code that don't work as expected and have resisted several hours of trying to find why. My reading of the purpose of an MWE is to strip away everything that preserves the error, by which time what is left of the code bears no resemblance to what it originally was meant to do, and may therefore appear quite senseless. However, my MWEs usually help to identify the culprits quite readily, this time it was `tl_gset` vs. `tl_set`, the answer supplied by Christian Hupfer.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth I understand and appreciate your efforts in minimizing the code. My last comment to your question was about the shown interface, more to future readers than to you, who surely know what your real macros do.

Comment: @egreg All good. Following your repeated suggestions to avoid sloppiness in the naming of variables and functions I have read the expl3 document, once again, and you and other readers on the TeX StackExchange may see some marked improvement in my future MWEs in this regard.